# Android. Как показать клавиатуру поверх accessibility overlay?

Tags: android, accessibility

Я добавил на accessibility оверлей `EditText`, и сначала у меня не показывалась клавиатура при нажатии на него, исправил сделав вызов клавиатуры при получении фокуса. Но беда в том, что весь оверлей рисуется поверх клавиатуры.

В маркете есть приложение, где сделано точно так же, и всё работает как надо и клавиатура открывается поверх оверлея. Даже режим плавающей клавиатуры работает поверх него, значит там это сделано не отступом вьюшки, а открытием клавиатуры поверх оверлея.

Как сделать то же самое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ответ то простой. Оказывается я показывал этот оверлей с флагом `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, по этому и текстовое поле не нажималось, и клавиатура показывалась под оверлеем